# Table of Contents: Customize space between dots before page number?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, page-numbering, koma-script

I am writing a small KOMA-Script `scrartcl` document with multiple sections. In the table of contents, LaTeX fills the current line with dots between the end of the section name and the page number. Is there any way to customize this behavior? I would like to reduce the space between the single dots (i.e. use more dots in the same space).

Comment: örn: that's not the default behavior of scrartcl. Section titles would be set without dots, subsections would produce dotted TOC lines. Perhaps show your settings, the best would be a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, I am referring to subsections (and subsubsections). However, this is a general question that is also interesting for other document classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For dotted TOC lines, standard LaTeX and also KOMA-Script use the internal macro `\@dotsep` which specifies that space in mu. Its original value is 4.5.

You could adjust it this way:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also specified the default setting.

Comment: @lockstep: Right! I thought the same and added it, right at the same time of your comment I guess. :-) I used `\show\@dotsep` first. Then I cross-checked: it's usually defined by the class, for example by `\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}` in the base classes.